# Removing character from start of line in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm coding a shell script to automatically setuop the configuration and directorys for an apache website. I've hit a problem where my `sed` command doesn't remove the default `#` from the start of the ServerName line. Could anyone help me change the command to work the way I need it to?

Thanks.

```
sudo sed -Ei "s|^([[:blank:]]*#ServerName).*$|\1 ${1.io|;
         s|^([[:blank:]]*DocumentRoot).*$|\1 \"/var/www/${1}/public\"|;
        " "/tmp/${1}.io.conf"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why should the command remove the hash? It is part of your capturing group.

If you want to remove it, [split the capturing group in two parts](https://regex101.com/r/loDoJ4/1/): one in front of the hash and one after it.

```
^([[:blank:]]*)#?(ServerName).*$
```